# How to Create Trusted windows form application

Tags: c#

I have created a notifier application which tells there's an update for the product application. I have registered my application for startup application. Problem I am encountering is my antivirus doesn't allow my program to run. How to solve this issue?

Comment: phone antivirus vendor support / submit a web ticket?... or just add an exception... read the manual?

Comment: Create an exception in your antivirus? We don't know which one you're using so and even if we did making an exception on an antivirus isnt a programming question so you'd best google your antivirus forum or something similar

Comment: But i can't tell which anti virus will the user will be using. so which all anti virus vendors i should consult?

Comment: Sometimes antivirus doesn't let applications run that are not signed with a codesigning certificate. Therefore it cannot validate the publisher of the application and its considered malicious.

Comment: You probably doing something suspicious (and only you know what you are doing) that makes antivirus think your application is virus.

Comment: ok.... thanks for reply @Bert Sinnema ...Which code signing certificate is good?

Answer (score 2):

You have to sign your application for your application trusted.

See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

If you want to just your application can be let by virus program. You can just create a setup for your application, then virus program will not make a trouble.

Of course if your application does not have any viruses, changing windows' own files or something like that.

Comment: http://ask-leo.com/why_do_some_programs_say_to_disable_antivirus_before_installing_and_should_i_turn_it_on_again_after.html
I have read this. And my program has "writing entries into the Windows registry" and "adding "auto-start" entries that launch programs whenever you boot your computer or login". so how can I make this trustable. I checked clickOnce but even ClickOnce is not working for me.. Please help me.

Comment: How can I know the problem of my program is that my program does't have digital signing?